# Add bootstrap row class on every n views rows

Tags: 7, views

I am using [Drupal Bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) and to get the correct positioning I am using bootstrap rows and columns classes.

How do I render a bootstrap row class on every let's say 3 view rows (bootstrap columns)? The structure must be like this

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="views-row col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="views-row col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="views-row col-md-4"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="views-row col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="views-row col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="views-row col-md-4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [views bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bootstrap) module, in views format style chose Bootstrap Grid it will solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

You add class in Unformatted list formate .[image]

and your class show like this

[image]

Answer (score -1):

[image]

You can use this.  Set number of columns 3 and apply custom row and column class